# Filling portions of a path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, fill

I have a path that represents a cupboard. I would like to fill each side of this cupboard with a different colour. How do i do so?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the down votes in this. Seems like a perfectly fine question to me.

Comment: btw this doesn't look like one path, it looks like 3 closed shapes. How many objects are actually there?

Comment: Because it is [covered in the official Help pages](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/live-paint-groups.html)?

Comment: Just a friendly reminder for everybody: Lacking research or not being interesting are valid reasons to *downvote* a question (just look at the hover text on the vote buttons). However, they are not valid reasons to *close* a question. If you disagree with this policy, take it to [meta]. Express your opinions on the qualities of this particular question with vote buttons. Use comments if you have specific suggestions how this question could be improved or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

If you go to window and pathfinding.

It comes up with a tool where you can click divide. It seperates it into its own groups!

then you can fill it out.

Yehaaa!

[image]